# Calling windowClosed on an EXIT_ON_CLOSE JFrame

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener, resource-cleanup

I have a small problem.

My Java application holds some native resources. I want to free those resources just before I exit the application. Therefore I wrote a `WindowListener` that frees those resources in `windowClosed` event.

The problem is that I am having a `JFrame` with `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, so when I close the window, it shuts down the JVM and the event will never reach me.

If I use `windowClosing` event, then somebody can actually override the closing event ater I freed the resources. This will then lead to segfaults in native code.

I can just put away the `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` and call `System.exit(0)` from the listener, but that does not seem clean to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe add a shutdown hook and free the native resources there? `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(Thread t)`. See more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

Comment: Nice, just what I needed. Cleanup from GUI didn't seem right, either.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the `JFrame` in the `windowClosing` before freeing the resources so you can make sure it doesn't get interrupted